# Convert String to date object in sprak

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark, date

i have a dataframe with column contain timestamp as a string the data like this

```
| created_at                     |
| -------------------------------|
| Thu Sep 12 06:54:21 +0000 2013 |
| Thu Sep 12 06:59:12 +0000 2013 |
| Thu Sep 12 07:01:22 +0000 2013 |
```

i want to convert this column to date object
i use spark(scala)

help me please, i dont know how to write the format please write a code!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `to_date` [function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#to_date(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,fmt:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column). You'll have to provide a datetime format string.